# Is this function, constructed by taking the maximum values between continuous functions, still continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> For each natural number $n$, let $f_n : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a continuous function, and for each $n$ let $h_n$ be defined by $h_n(x) = \max\{f_1(x),\ldots,f_n(x)\}$. Show that for each $n$ the function $h_n$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. Must the function $h$ defined by $h(x) = \sup\{f_n(x) : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be continuous?

I solved the first part, i.e. the finite case this way:
Let, for every $i$, $f_{n_i}$ be the function $f_n$ which takes the highest values on $[x_i$,$x_{i-1}[$. Then $h_n=f_{n_i}$ in this interval, and hence $h_n$ is continuous in every open intervals $]x_i$,$x_{i+1}[$. Defining $g_i(x)=f_{n_i}(x)-f_{n_{i-1}}(x)$, we have $g_i(x)$ is continuous (being the sum of continuous functions), $g_i(x)<0$ for $x_{i-1}<x<x_i$, and $g(x_i)\ge 0$. So, by continuity, $g(x_i)=0$, and $f_{n_{i-1}}(x_i)=f_{n_i}(x_i)$. Therefore $h_n(x)$ is continuous also in each $x_i$, so it is continuous.

However I'm not sure if this covers also in the infinite case, which is the second part of the problem.

Comment: I tried to clean this up because it was pretty rough but you should make sure it's correct.

Comment: Consider $f_n(x) = x^{1/n}$.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, thanks for making it more clear.

Comment: The function need not be defined. Take $f_n(x) = n$. You need to add conditions to make sure it is defined first before trying to establish continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f_n$ to be the continuous function whose graph is given by connecting the following points by straight lines $(0,0), ({1 \over 2},0), ({1 \over 2} + {1 \over n},1), (1,1)$.

We see that $h(x) = 1_{({1 \over 2},1]}(x)$ which is not continuous.